# Stop and Take a Breath!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I've been to the carnival; I've been to the robber's den.
>
> I've seen judges who are just and unjust.
>
> Can't really judge them; I've been one to make mistakes, too.
>
> I've also seen twins eating a delicious green fruit.
>
> I've sat down in a comfortable rocker,
>
> and eaten a steak pink in the middle.
>
> What a busy fellow I am, yet I don't have a worry.
>
> I've done and seen a lot, and all from a challenge,
>
> But what have I never seen?

*Thanks for reading this puzzle! As usual, please include with your answer an explanation for each line of the riddle. (Every line in this puzzle contributes something, by the way)*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are

> **AIR**

Each line of the riddle is a description of

> one or more words that rhyme with "air."

I've been to the carnival; I've been to the robber's den.

> FAIR and LAIR

I've seen judges who are just and unjust.

> FAIR (again) and UNFAIR

Can't really judge them; I've been one to make mistakes, too.

> ERR (from @arbitrahj)

I've also seen twins eating a delicious green fruit.

> PAIR and PEAR

I've sat down in a comfortable rocker,

> CHAIR

and eaten a steak pink in the middle.

> RARE

What a busy fellow I am, yet I don't have a worry.

> CARE (you "don't have a care")

I've done and seen a lot, and all from a challenge,

> DARE

But what have I never seen?

> Perhaps this one is AIR again, since it is invisible to the human eye.

Title: Stop and Take a Breath!

> People breathe in air in order to calm themselves down.

Comment: Very nice! This is, of course, the correct solution. As far as the missing line, "make mistakes" is the synonym I had in mind. I think I'll let this question get a little more publicity before I give you the checkmark.

Comment: Ah, I see, I think @arbitrahj has the right answer to that one (sorry for answer sniping you btw!)

Comment: Complete now. Great job!

Comment: Great answer, no worries on the snipe, I’m a fan of your puzzles!

Comment: @arbitrahj Thanks, and you're an excellent puzzle solver! :)

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer to get things rolling...

I've been to the carnival; I've been to the robber's den.

> Faire, Lair

I've seen judges who are just and unjust.

> Fair, UnFair

Can't really judge them; I've been one to make mistakes, too.

> ??? , err

I've also seen twins eating a delicious green fruit.

> Pair, pear

I've sat down in a comfortable rocker,

> Chair

and eaten a steak pink in the middle.

> Rare

What a busy fellow I am, yet I don't have a worry.

> ??? , care

I've done and seen a lot, and all from a challenge,

> ??? , dare

But what have I never seen?

> Air??

Comment: Very close; looks like you got sniped :( Good work, though!

Comment: Indeed, you have unfortunately been sniped. But fear not, for in two days hereafter, I will award your answer a bounty (probably of $100+$ rep to make up for a $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ given that this question is on a roll at the moment) :P

Comment: @MrPie I wish there were more people like you - and also, thanks for the extra publicity ;)

Comment: Wow. I didn’t know that was possible!

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about this.... and then for some reason, I remembered whilst I was procrastinating. A belated congratulations for an extra 100 rep! :D